# changing ember RESTAdapter get request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

at the moment, when ember is asking for child data through the rest adapater, it makes a GET request with the following options:

```
http://localhost/orders?ids%5B%5D=0x0000000000000386&ids%5B%5D=0x00000000000003a4&ids%5B%5D=0x00000000000003cf&ids%5B%5D=0x0000000000000631&ids%5B%5D=0x0000000000000639
```

which equates to parameters of

```
ids[]:0x0000000000000386
ids[]:0x00000000000003a4
ids[]:0x00000000000003cf
ids[]:0x0000000000000631
ids[]:0x0000000000000639
```

I was wondering if there was a way of changing that to be either

```
id1:0x0000000000000386
id2:0x00000000000003a4
id3:0x00000000000003cf
id4:0x0000000000000631
id5:0x0000000000000639
```

or

```
 {ids: [{"id":"0x0000000000000386"},
        {"id":"0x00000000000003a4"},
        {"id":"0x00000000000003cf},"
        {"id":"0x0000000000000631"},
        {"id":"0x0000000000000639"}
  ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using the "links" option in the data.

Within the json returned at the higher level , include the links

```
{customers : [
    {name": "foobar inc",
     "links": {"orders:/customers/181/orders"}
    }]
}
```

so now when ember tries to get the orders of a customer, it will make a json request to the url specified in the links

this works really well for me. It also has the advantage of not having to load all children in as either ids[] or sideloading.